# Why does Linux NETLINK man page provide C++ examples but not C?

Tags: c++, c, linux, manpage, netlink

I dealt with [netlink](/questions/tagged/netlink) API and examine its man pages [netlink(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/netlink.3.html) and [netlink(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/netlink.7.html).
Suddenly I faced with such construction:

```
struct msghdr msg;

msg = { &sa, sizeof(sa), &iov, 1, NULL, 0, 0 };
```

I tried it in C, but it gives the error:

> error: expected expression before ‘{’ token

Apparently it's [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) (I don't know what standard).
Of course it's obvious that Netlink is an API and has no particular language binding. But this is C implementation and all MAN pages I've seen about C API have pure C examples. Why there is no note about the language used in examples? What is this practice for and why is this not f.e. on Python or whatever?

---

UPD: I don't think it's a typo or an unintentional error in MAN page. There are some other places with this C++ feature using, e.g.:

```
struct iovec iov = { buf, sizeof(buf) };
struct sockaddr_nl sa;
struct msghdr msg;
struct nlmsghdr *nh;

msg = { &sa, sizeof(sa), &iov, 1, NULL, 0, 0 };
len = recvmsg(fd, &msg, 0);

for (nh = (struct nlmsghdr *) buf; NLMSG_OK (nh, len);
     nh = NLMSG_NEXT (nh, len)) {
...
```

It looks like a conscious choice of C++.

Comment: The question is taking one tiny example and asserting it applies more widely.. the question really is "Why does *this specific [netlink] man page* provide an example which does not compile locally as C?" (File a bug report, perhaps.)

Comment: And there *is* an implicit language "binding", being merely exposed as a particular language with a particular set calling conventions - be it C or C++ or whatnot. C (or even C++ as the case may apply) happen to be the *native* "binding" of the library. Just as a Python module documentation..

Comment: @z0lupka No. That's a large leap to make from an *example that merely fails to compile in C*.. C++ has quite a bit of just-work-like-C compatibility (ie. using `printf` in C++ doesn't make `printf` a C++ function). Maybe it's a typo that went unnoticed..

Comment: @Eljay I know C pretty well, but thanks.

Comment: @user2864740 You edited your comment. So what about binding? C++ is implicit *native* binding here? Strongly doubt.

Comment: @z0lupka See C++ name mangling and ABI, etc. Have fun using an arbitrary C++ library in C. The "binding" of a C++ library is for C++ and to use it in C requires significant hurdles (see SWIG, C-friendly [read: not C++] API exposure, etc.).

Comment: `Apparently it's c++` How do you know it's C++? Do you have any reference for that?

Comment: @Eljay You can initialize, but you can't assign like that.

Comment: @user2864740 What do you want to prove to me? That writing C++ examples in the MAN page of C library is normal? Btw without any notice. I still don't think so..

Comment: I think this is just an anomaly. Normally Unix man pages use C syntax, I think the author of this one just screwed up.

Comment: @Barmar • Yep, you are correct.  I've not done C in a while.  I've deleted my misleading / incorrect comment.

Comment: He probably meant to write `struct msghdr msg = { ... };`, but for some reason he split them up into separate statements.

Comment: @KamilCuk *"How do you know it's C++?"* - **any other options?**

Comment: Yes, it's a bug.

Comment: Example compiles in `C++`, but is not pure `C++` code (it would look a bit different). I would say this is `C` code with one small C++ feature. Here is [equivalent examle](https://www.godbolt.org/z/PJ7_3X). Basically error in documentation which is so painless that it is ignore by everyone.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the assertion is false.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks about offsite documentation, which is similar to asking for [support for offsite resources](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745).

Comment: `There are some other places with this C++ feature using` - you posted the same code `msg = { &sa, sizeof(sa), &iov, 1, NULL, 0, 0 };`. Where is that other place exactly where C++ feature is used?

Comment: @KamilCuk There are two different places with `msg` initialization. But OK, perhaps it just someone's negligence..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why does Linux man page provides C++ examples but not C?

Linux man pages provide C examples. They don't provide C++ examples.

> I tried it in C, but it gives the error:

It's an error in the documentation. It's meant to be:

```
struct msghdr msg = { &sa, sizeof(sa), &iov, 1, NULL, 0, 0 };
```

I believe you could post a bug report on linux-man mailing list.

> Why there is no note about the language used in examples?

As stated [on the project homepage](https://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/), Linux man pages document the Linux kernel and the C library interface. The Linux kernel is written in C (primarily, [there is some assembly, etc.](https://www.openhub.net/p/linux/analyses/latest/languages_summary)). As such, Linux man pages serve examples in the C programming language.

> What is this practice for and why is this not f.e. on Python or whatever?

The practice is that C language is used in the development of Linux. It's not Python or any other language, because the Linux kernel is written in the C programming language. The Linux kernel is written in the C programming language because the creator of the Linux kernel, Linus Torvalds, made a decision a very long time ago to write the kernel in the C programming language.

It's easiest for kernel developers to distribute kernel interface API for user-space programs in the language the kernel is written itself, so they don't have to rewrite it all for user-space programs in another programming language. They also can use for example the same header file that user-space uses in the kernel itself. That, for example, reduces bugs and workload, etc. As such, it's easiest for kernel developers to provide the documentation using examples written in the  C programming language.

Comment: This specific example, `struct msghdr` and `sendmsg()`, and the other APIs used are from userspace C libraries.  So it really not so much in C because the kernel is in C, but because the userspace libraries being used are C libraries.  Those userspace libraries and headers being in C is of course related to the kernel being written in C.

Comment: Even after the correction it's still erroneous. The order of members (and absence of other intervening members) in `msghdr` is unspecified. You need to either use designated initializers or assignment of members to use `msghdr` correctly.

Comment: @KamilCuk Thank you for clarifying! But the statement about the error is somewhat doubtful.. Updated my question.

Comment: I don't understand, why would you doubt it? Linux man pages _by intent_ don't want to provide C++ api. The headers are written in C, `extern "C"` can be missing in netlink headers, `recvmsg` (or any other function exported by netlink) function is not mangled according to C++.